# Application flickering issue in android listview

Tags: android, listview, flicker

I have a listview in my application and each row of the listview a frame layout with an imageview and a button above the imageview the list scrolls normally when it is scrolled by touching the image but when I scroll the listview by touching the button above the image the listview flickers and behaves abnormally.
Someone please help with this issue

Answer (score 0):

this may helps you

```
listview.setSmoothScrollbarEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Thank you
but it is a horizontal listview so it does not have the setSmoothScrollbarEnabled property...